# Is this definition of likelihood presented in an arxived article correct?

Tags: bayesian, likelihood

In a recently [arxived article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.09054.pdf) the following definition of the *likelihood* is given:

> The Bayes rule provides the posterior probability $p(h_i|o)$ for each hypothesis given the observation:
>
> $$p(hi|o) = \frac{p(o|hi)p(hi)}{p(o)}\;\;(2)$$
>
> where $p(o|h_i)$ is the probability of obtaining the observation
>   given the ith-hypothesis, and $p(hi)$ and $p(o)$ are the probability of $h_i$ and the observation $o$, respectively. The hypothesis $h_{max}$ that maximizes (2) is known as the *estimate* and provides the most likely combination of parameters that reproduces the observations. Finding the *estimate* is equivalent to estimating the free parameters, while the width of the likelihood distribution provides a measure of their confidence intervals. **The quantity obtained by dividing Eq. (2)
>   by $p(h_{max}|o)$ is referred to as the likelihood $L(h_i|o)$**
>
> $$L(hi|o) = \frac{p(o|h_i)p(h_i)}{p(o|h_{max})p(h_{max})}$$

I have never seen the likelihood written this way. Is this definition correct?

Comment: A link to the article in question could help provide some context here.

Comment: Ok, [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.09054.pdf) it is. I didn't post it because I felt like I was "snitching" on the authors.

Comment: I added the link to your question in case your comment with the link gets lost. One purpose of arXiv is for authors to get constructive feedback on their work, so I don't think this is "snitching" at all. If this does end up to be a deficiency in the article then the authors should know sooner rather than later.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is called the posterior. For completion,

1. $p(o|hi)$ is called the likelihood
2. $p(hi)$ is called the prior
3. $p(hi|o)$ is called the posterior